# Javascript - Reduce Method over array. Add point value of cards together to get a total

Tags: javascript

Currently, it is console logging:

```
14
16
[ { suit: '♣', value: 'J', points: 10 },
  { suit: '♥', value: 4, points: 4 } ]
[ { suit: '♥', value: 'K', points: 10 },
  { suit: '♣', value: 6, points: 6 },
  { suit: '♠', value: 'J', points: 10 } ]
0[object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

I only care about the last 3 objects being logged. The points of 10, 6, 10, which should give me 26.

dealerHand and playerHand are both arrays that have 2 cards pushed into them from the beginning. The dealerHand array will continue to "hit" or add cards if the total point value is less than 17.

After it adds a 3rd card, it logs the 0 and returns arrays of objects.

I believe the reduce method is a good way to get the total within an array, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////
                CODE
///////////////////////////////////////////////
const dealRandomCard = () => {
     return deckOfCards.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
            deckOfCards.length), 1)[0];
}

// console.log(dealRandomCard());

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                DEAL 2 CARDS TO EACH SIDE                 //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
     playerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
     dealerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
  }
```

The dealRandomCard method is just returning one random card from the array that I have defined as deckOfCards with the appropriate suit, value, and points that can be added together to determine a winner.

```
let playerPoints = 0,
    dealerPoints = 0;

for (let { points } of playerHand) {
    playerPoints += points;
}

for (let { points } of dealerHand) {
    dealerPoints += points
}
    console.log(playerPoints);
    console.log(dealerPoints);

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let totalPoints;

if (dealerPoints < 17) {
    dealerHand.push(dealRandomCard());

    totalPoints += points

} else {

    return

}

let totalDealerPoints = 0;

// for (let card of dealerHand) {

 totalDealerPoints += points;

 totalDealerPoints  = dealerHand.reduce((total , amount) => total + 
 amount, 0);
 // }

// return totalDealerPoints
console.log(playerHand);
console.log(dealerHand);
console.log(totalDealerPoints);
```

///////// REVISED WITH CORRECT WORKING CODE /////////////

```
 let totalPoints = 0;

 if (dealerPoints < 17) {
    dealerHand.push(dealRandomCard());

   totalPoints += points

 } else {

  return

 }



 // for (let card of dealerHand) {

 totalPoints += points;

 totalPoints  = dealerHand.reduce((total , card) => total + 
 card.points, 0);
```

Comment: What is `dealRandomCard`?

Comment: You are using a variable `points` in the second half of this that is not defined (you use a local version of `points` in the for loops).

Comment: edited for clarity, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like code is missing because in lines like this:

```
    dealerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
    totalPoints += points
```

`points` is not defined anywhere in the current scope and `totalPoints` was not initialized to zero. But since these values aren't really being used, I'm not sure what to say.

Regarding the `reduce`, you will get a card with each pass through, so you need to add the `card.points`:

```js
let dealerHand = [ 
  { suit: '♥', value: 'K', points: 10 },
  { suit: '♣', value: 6, points: 6 },
  { suit: '♠', value: 'J', points: 10 } ]

let totalPoints = dealerHand.reduce((total, card) => total + card.points, 0)
console.log(totalPoints)
```

Comment: Appreciate it. My mistake as I had points defined globally, not shown in code. Also I have initialized totalPoints to 0 and added card.points to the arguments